# organizing font family usage, site colors, etc

Tags: css

If I want to limit font family usage across my site, say to 2 or 3 font different typefaces (e.g. Times, Arial, etc).  Is there a way I can organize my CSS so that I have something like

```
 fontType1 is font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 fontType2 is font-family: Arial, sans-serif
```

Then for each of my UI elements that I style in the CSS, pick from the available font types, i.e. fontType1, fontType2.  Likewise for my set of color choices.

If I change the font-family of fontType1, I want it go all the way across the site/stylesheet. I don't want to have to go into each css declaration and change it.  If I want to change one of my site's "dark colors", I want it to go all the way across the site; I don't want to go into each usage of it and change it.

Comment: ... if limiting font-styles like this is not good, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question seems to be your answer. Just pick one of those as the class of each of your UI elements.

Comment: really don't know what you mean..can you explain further?

Comment: If I change the font-style of font1, I want it go all the way across the site.  I don't want to have to go into each css declaration, and then change it.

Comment: so you're asking if you can set a css variable? Like http://sass-lang.com/ ?

Comment: Sorry, I fat fingered this question -- meant font-family. Please see edited question.

Comment: @Inrbob -- yes, like saas gives, but without needing a pre-processor.  Is there a technique to do it in the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the best way (without using a preprocessor) would be:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
.button, .promo{ /* Your list of selectors that need to use this font stack */
    font-family:one;
}

p,ul,
.small-print,.error{ /* Your list of selectors that need to use this font stack */
    font-family:two;
}

#nav,#footer{ /* Your list of selectors that need to use this font stack */
    font-family:three;
}
```

This doesn't rely on JS, it won't bloat your HTML, and the best thing is that you can update all instances at once :)

This way you only need to add new selectors to your list, and don't have to redefine your families. Have that in a 'Shared' section. I write about it here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/26/writing-css-for-others/ (do a find for 'Shared').

H

Comment: Thanks H -- this looks like an approach that will work, although I will have to update the list every time I add a new selector.  Perhaps doing this extra step and the maintenance of having a Table of Contents, as you described in your article, is a good step.  I'm going to keep this question open just a little longer, to see if anyone has another technique to accomplish this end goal -- i.e. common fonts and colors used throughout.

Comment: Adding a selector to the list is no more effort than adding a declaration to a ruleset. You'd have to write something somewhere if you want a new element to adopt the styling :)

Comment: Yah, good point.  And the organization seems like a benefit -- seeing what uses what in your whole site / stylesheet.  I'm liking it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this directly with CSS but it's one of the major features of libraries such as [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). LESS can be compiled by server-side or client-side Javascript, and Sass is compiled with Ruby. Compass is a library that allows compiling Sass outside the context of a Rails or Ruby web app.

Here's an example of what you can do with Sass:

```
$color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: $color;
}
h2 {
  color: $color;
}
```

And the CSS that it's compiled into:

```
#header {
  color: #4D926F;
}
h2 {
  color: #4D926F;
}
```

In addition to variables, as shows above, you also get mixins (which are basically functions) and nested selectors.

Comment: Thanks Emily.  Looks like Grails (what I'm using) has a Compass plug-in, so this is another option to use.

Comment: The problem we have here is that you're sending more code than necessary down the wire, you repeat `color: #4D926F;` twice which is against the DRY principle. If you were to write: 

`$color: #4D926F;` 

`#header,h2{` 
`color: $color;` 
`}` 

It'd compile as: 

`#header,h2 {` 
`color: #4D926F;` 
`}` 

Which does exactly the same but serves the end user only as much code as they need :)

H

Answer (score 0):

Have something like so:

```
.font-type1 { font-family: font1, font2, font3; }
.font-type2 { font-family: font4, font5, font6; }
.font-type3 { font-family: font7, font8, font9; }
```

And set them on the `<body>` element.

---

If you wish to dynamically change it with JavaScript:

### HTML

```
<a class=changefont data-font="font-type1" href=#>Font 1</a>
<a class=changefont data-font="font-type2" href=#>Font 2</a>
<a class=changefont data-font="font-type3" href=#>Font 3</a>
```

### JavaScript

And with javascript (I'm using jQuery for simplicity, can be done with js alone too)

```
$('.changefont').click(function() { $('body').removeClass().addClass($(this).data('font')); });
```

**[Here's an Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/h2fma/)**

---

By changing a higher level ancestor class, you cause a nice cascade (**Cascading** Style Sheet) over the entire document.

Comment: Thanks Rikudo.  Please note my goal isn't to update them dynamically, I just want to have my fonts and colors all defined in one place in the CSS, and then be able to use those as I make styles in my CSS.  Is this possible to do "statically", or must one seek to do it dynamically, per your example?

Comment: No, you don't need, read the last sentence: "By changing a higher level ancestor class, you cause a nice cascade (Cascading Style Sheet) over the entire document."

Comment: - Thanks Rikudo, this confused me.  I.e. how do I then use font-type1 for some elements, and font-type2 for others?

Comment: that one's easy, apply the class on them in the HTML, `<p class="font-type2">Lorem Ipsum</p>` etc.

Comment: Yah, I see.  But I want to build a whole element's style, like .cartItem { declaration1; declaration 2; etc }, and then adjust the font-family of those "ui elements" in one place in my stylesheet.  So if I had styles for 50 elements, 20 might use font-type1, 30 might use font-type2.  Then, if I change the font family of font-type1, all those 20 elements get updated.

Comment: I'm thinking that wouldn't work with the way you recommended,but am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is adding some classes to UI elements.

CSS:

```
.fontType1 {font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif}
.fontType2 {font-family: Arial, sans-serif}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="fontType1">Header 1</h1>
<p class="someOtherCssClass fontType2">paragraph text goes here</p>
```